# How to add a variable contains a string to url imported from another file?

Tags: python, python-behave

I am writing a test in Behave with Python.
In `environment.py` I have declared a `url` variable with a URL.
In `step.py` I wrote a function that calls this `environment.url` and I want to add to the URL a string that is saved in another variable. This is the code:

```
@when('I call for a GET request for user {user}')
def my_user(context, user):
    response = requests.get(environment.url, user)
```

When I print `environment.url` it prints the correct URL.
When I print the user it prints the correct user coming from the feature file.
But I cannot add them together!

I tried `+ '/jhon'` and it works fine, but when I try with the variable it doesn't.

Comment: what do you get from `print(type(user))`?

Comment: What happens when you try to add them together?

Comment: what is the code of the `when` decorator

Comment: print(type(user)) = <class 'str'>

Comment: when adding them together it just going to the main url without the user

Comment: The when code:
```
  Scenario: Get a specific user details from mysite
    When I call for a GET request for user "/john"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try this:
concat = str(environment.url)+"/"+str(user)
print(concat)
```

This should work, feel free to show the results.

Comment: This is the result:
```https://api.mysite.com/users/"/john"```
How do i get ride of the "

Comment: So i moved the "" from the feature file and it worked!
Thanks Samuel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).